# Sufficient conditions for continuous functions of continuous random variables to themselves be continuous random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I've been trying to figure out nontrivial conditions for continuous functions of continuous random variables to themselves be continuous random variables without much success. Here's what I know so far:

1. Continuous functions of continuous random variables are random variables, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852184/proving-if-x-is-a-random-variable-and-f-is-a-continuous-function-then-fx) thread
2. Continuous functions of continuous random variables needn't be continuous random variables in general, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842243/a-continuous-random-variable-map-by-continuous-function-will-become-continuous) counterexample.
3. Strictly monotonic functions of continuous random variables are continuous random variables

Are there more general conditions under which a continuous/smooth/analytic function of a continuous random variable is itself a continuous random variable?

Ultimately, what I am after is the following: if $\Omega$ is a continuous random variable with a bounded density function and $f$ is a continuous/smooth/analytic function, then what are some general conditions for the density function of $f(\Omega)$, if it exists, to be bounded?

**Edit**: As per @Malkin's comments, I want to clarify that by a continuous random variable, I mean a random variable that has a continuous cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.). I am also interested in the case when the c.d.f. is absolutely continuous, see the previous paragraph.

Comment: I have changed my answer so that it uses a better definition of a continuous random variable. Could you please confirm that this is the definition that you are using?

Comment: @Malkin Thanks for your efforts! I have clarified the definition of a continuous random variable I am using in the question as per your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim 1:**

If $f$ is any function that is constant on some interval $I$ then there exists a continuous random variable $X$ such that $f(X)$ is not a continuous random variable.

**Proof:**

Suppose $f$ is constant on $I=[a,b]$ with $a \neq b$ and let $X \sim N(0,1)$. Put $$\varepsilon :=P(X \in I)>0$$ $$Y:=f(X)$$ $$F_Y(x)=P(Y \leq x)$$ $$x_0:=f(a)=f(b)$$
Then $\forall \, \delta>0$ we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\vert F_Y(x_0)-F_Y(x_0-\delta) \vert &= P \left( Y \in (x_0-\delta, x_0]\right)
\\ &= P \left( f(X) \in (x_0-\delta,x_0] \right)
\\ &\geq P \left( f(X) =x_0 \right)
\\ &\geq P \left( X \in I \right)
\\ &= \varepsilon
\end{align}
$$

Hence $F_Y$ is not continuous at $x_0$ and $f(X)$ is not a continuous random variable.

**Claim 2:**

If $f$ is any real analytic function that is not constant on any interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $f(X)$ is a continuous random variable for any continuous random variable $X$.

**Proof:**

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with CDF $F_X$ and let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be the range of $f$. Define $Y := f(X)$ and let $F_Y$ be the CDF of $Y$, so that $F_Y$ has domain $U$. We will show that $F_Y$ is continuous.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x_0 \in U$.

By simple properties of random variables, $P(\vert X \vert > M) \rightarrow 0$ as $M \rightarrow \infty$. Pick $M$ such that $P(\vert X \vert > M) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Now consider $S=f^{-1}(\{x_0\})$. Because $f$ is not constant on any interval, $S$ consists of countably many points: $S=\{s_i\}_{i \in J}$ for some $J \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Define $S':=S \cap [-M,M]$. Suppose $S'$ contains infinitely many points. Then, since $S'$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence $(s_{i_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $s_{i_n} \rightarrow c$ for some $c \in S'$. Since $f(s_{i_n})=x_0 \, \forall \, n$ by Rolle's Theorem we have a sequence $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $s_{i_n} \leq r_n<s_{i_{n+1}}$ and $f'(r_n)=0 \, \forall \, n$. Also $s_{i_n} \rightarrow c \implies r_n \rightarrow c$. But by [this reasoning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878880/real-differentiable-function-with-sequence-of-turning-points-that-tend-to-a-limi/2878883#2878883), such a sequence $(r_n)$ cannot exist for an analytic function $f$. And so $S'$ must only contain finitely many points. Re-label them $S'=\{s'_i\}_{i=1}^N$.

$F_X$ continuous $\implies$ for each $s'_i \, \exists \, \delta_i>0$ s.t. $\vert F_X(x)-F_X(y) \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2N} \, \, \forall \, x,y \in (s'_i-\delta_i, s'_i+ \delta_i)$

Consider $f'(s'_i)$. Suppose $f'(s'_i)=0$. Since $f$ is not constant on any interval and since $f'$ is differentiable, $\exists \, \gamma_i>0$ s.t. $f$ is monotonic on $(s'_i,s'_i+\gamma_i)$ and monotonic on $(s'_i-\gamma_i,s'_i)$. If instead $f'(s'_i) \neq 0$ then again $\exists \, \gamma_i>0$ s.t. $f$ is monotonic on $(s'_i,s'_i+\gamma_i)$ and monotonic on $(s'_i-\gamma_i,s'_i)$. (See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83802/is-there-an-analytic-function-which-is-not-monotone-on-any-interval) for a justification.)

Define $k:=\frac{1}{2}\min\{\delta_i,\gamma_i \}_i$ and $t:=\frac{1}{2} \min\{\vert f(s'_i+k)-f(s'_i)\vert ,\vert f(s'_i-k)-f(s'_i)\vert \}_i$.

Constructing $k$ and $t$ in this way gives us that $(s'_i-k, s'_i+ k) \subset (s'_i-\delta_i, s'_i+ \delta_i) \, \forall \, i$ ; that $f$ is monotonic on $(s'_i-k, s'_i) \, \forall \, i$ and separately on $(s'_i, s'_i+ k) \, \forall \, i $ ; and then that $(x_0-t,x_0+t]=(f(s'_i)-t,f(s'_i)+t] \subset f((s'_i-k,s'_i+k])\, \forall \, i$. These facts will be used in the working below.

Let $x \in (x_0-t,x_0 + t)$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
\vert F_Y(x)-F_Y(x_0) \vert &\leq P \left( Y \in (x_0-t,x_0+t] \right)
\\ &= P \left( f(X) \in (x_0-t,x_0+t] \right)
\\ &= P \left( X \in f^{-1}((x_0-t,x_0+t]) \right)
\\ &\leq P \left( X \in f^{-1}((x_0-t,x_0+t]) \cap [-M,M] \right) + P(\vert X \vert > M)
\\ &= P \left( X \in f^{-1}((x_0-t,x_0+t]) \cap [-M,M] \right) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &\leq P \left( X \in \bigcup_i (s'_i-k,s'_i+k] \right) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &\leq \sum_i \vert F_X(s'_i+k)-F_X(s'_i-k) \vert + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &\leq \sum_i \frac{\varepsilon}{2N}+ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &= \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &= \varepsilon
\end{align}
$$

Hence $F_Y$ is continuous.

We may conclude that $f(X)$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I correct in understanding that this only provides a necessary condition on the function $f$?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's only halfway done. We have that if $f$ is a continuous function s.t. $f(X)$ is a continuous r.v. for any continuous r.v. $X$ then $f$ cannot be constant on any interval. We don't quite have that if $f$ is any continuous function that isn't constant on any interval then $f(X)$ is a continuous r.v. for any continuous r.v. $X$...

Comment: I have a feeling that if $f$ is a smooth/analytic function which isn't constant on any interval and $X$ is a continuous r.v., then $f(X)$ will be a continuous r.v. because $f(x) = c$ cannot have uncountably infinite number of solutions for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If we use the definition of a continuous r.v. that the c.d.f. is absolutely continuous, then maybe countably infinite turning points doesn't hurt us since the union of a countably infinite set of measure zero is measure zero?

Comment: @madnessweasley I think I've done it! I have edited the answer to prove that if $f$ is analytic and not constant on any interval then $f(X)$ is a continuous r.v.
I reckon there's a more elegant proof out there, but I'm confident that this chunky one works.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts! It looks like there might be some hope for replacing the condition "f is analytic and is nonconstant on any interval" with "f has a finite number of critical points" plus some milder differentiability conditions...

Comment: Yes, "$f$ has a finite number of stationary points and is twice differentiable" could replace "$f$ is analytic and not constant on any interval"